# Why Html.BeginForm in MVC4 is affected by the button click event,does it happen in MVC5?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5

My web page have a button and a form,I use `@Html.BeginForm` to produce the form and when I click the button,I will jump to the login page.To my surprise,when I click the button,the form post to my controller automatically.But when I use  `@using (Html.BeginForm`,it seems OK.

**My web page**

```
 <button  onclick="logout()">logout</button>
  @Html.BeginForm("ExportFile", "Student",  new { id = "exportForm" }))
{
@Html.Hidden("year")
@Html.Hidden("fileName")
}
```

**My new web page will work well**

```
 <button  onclick="logout()">logout</button>
   @using (Html.BeginForm("ExportFile", "Student",  new { id = "exportForm" })))
{
@Html.Hidden("year")
@Html.Hidden("fileName")
}
```

I find the different HTML is  `System.Web.Mvc.Html.MvcForm)`:

```
<form id="exportForm" method="post" action="/Student/ExportFile">
System.Web.Mvc.Html.MvcForm) {
<input id="year" type="hidden" value="" name="year">
<input id="fileName" type="hidden" value="" name="fileName">
}
```

What is the difference between then?Someone teach me to add  `@{Html.EndForm();}` when I using `@Html.BeginForm`,but it seems not work.May be it works in MVC3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use these two methods only if you add the button type.

```
<button  onclick="logout()" type="buttton">logout</button>
```

Comment: But when I use  `@using` to produce the form,I even can not add the button.Can you tell me why?

Answer (score 1):

The using statement automatically adds the closing tag for the form's HTML. You should always use @using if you are using Html.BeginForm().

Comment: No，in mvc4 using Html.BeginForm() it will close without using @{Html.EndForm();}.I check it from the html codes.

Comment: I didn't say anything about Html.EndForm. If you don't use the using statement, the namespace is generated in the HTML. All the using statement does is automatically call Html.EndForm.